# What are the execution contexts in P2300R4?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, language-lawyer, executioncontext, c++23

I'm referring to [P2300R4](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2300r4.html), which is long and difficult, given my current level, but I want to understand more about it.

It refers to *execution contexts* since the beginning

> **§ 1. Introduction**
>
> This paper proposes a self-contained design for a Standard C++ framework for managing asynchronous execution on generic execution contexts. […]

and keeps referring to these contexts throughout the paper, but I haven't really understood what they are.

The following excerpt is supposed to explain what an execution context is, at least based on the first few words:

> **§ 4.1. Execution contexts describe the place of execution**
>
> An **execution context** is a resource that represents the *place* where execution will happen. This could be a concrete resource - like a specific thread pool object, or a GPU - or a more abstract one, like the current thread of execution. Execution contexts don’t need to have a representation in code; they are simply a term describing certain properties of execution of a function.

But I really don't understand.

---

To give some more context about what level I'm at, I could understand without much difficulties [the](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2300r4.html#example-async-inclusive-scan) [three](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2300r4.html#example-async-inclusive-scan) [examples](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2300r4.html#example-async-dynamically-sized-read) in the [§ 1.3 Examples: End User](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2300r4.html#example-end-user) section, probably only thanks to the bit of Haskell I know, but then I had to fly over § 1.4-1.6 (I'll probably try to read [§ 1.4.1.3 Echo server](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2300r4.html#example-end-user) which I might understand if I make some more effort); I could understand [§ 1.7.1 Composability with `execution::let_*`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2300r4.html#example-server-let) and probably also [the following section](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2300r4.html#example-server-on).

However, I also have to clarify that I when I write *I understand* I mostly mean that I can read the code snippets and tell what they do, but I don't necessarily have a preception of *how* they work, e.g. I mostly understand what is the role of `| ex::let_error(some_fun)` (and similar bits) in a pipeline, but I wouldn't be able to guess how `ex::let_error` could be implemented to have that effect.

Comment: "Introduction" section gives a link to [an earlier paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0443r14.html) that, among other things, defines the term "execution context".